# cout resulting terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

Tags: c++

When I run my program It crashes with the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>     what():  basic_string::_S_create
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I am getting that with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Cargo
{
    string nm;
public:
    Cargo(const string& name): nm(name)
    {

    }
    Cargo& operator=(const Cargo& )
    {
        cout<<"inside Cargo::operator=()"<<endl;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Cargo& ca)
    {
        return os<<"Cargo name: "<<ca.nm;
    }
};

class Truck
{
    Cargo b;
    string name;
public:
    Truck(const string& nm):b("Cargo" + name)
    {
        name = nm;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "name: " << name << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Truck a("Truck a"), b("Truck b");
    a = b;
    a.print();
    b.print();
}///~:
```

Comment: At this point `b("Cargo" + name)` in the constructor of `Truck`, `name` is uninitialized.

Comment: @RichardCritten, tks, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Truck` constructor:

```
Truck(const string& nm):b("Cargo" + name)
{
    name = nm;
}
```

You are sending as parameter to `b` the `name` attribute of your `Truck` class, which is not initialized. I guess you wanted to pass your `nm` parameter instead:

```
Truck(const string& nm):b("Cargo" + nm)
{
    name = nm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In truck you have `b("Cargo" + name)`.  `name` has no value yet as you have not entered the constructor.  If you change it to `b("Cargo" + nm)` it will fix the run-time erorr.  See [this](https://ideone.com/OtFS3A) live example

You should also initialize `name` in the intializer list as:

```
Truck(const string& nm):b("Cargo" + nm), name(nm) {}
```

It is okay to have an empty constructor and I prefer to do that as it shows all the constructor is doing is initializing member variables and nothing else.

Comment: Explaining the error message a bit more: member variables are constructed in the order of declaration; so `"Cargo" + name` is actually processed before `name` has had its constructor called, causing undefined behaviour.